# Using Regex to pull out a part of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't figure out how to pull out multiple matches from the following example:

This code:

```
/prefix-(\w+)/g.exec('prefix-firstname prefix-lastname');
```

returns:

```
["prefix-firstname", "firstname"]
```

How do I get it to return:

```
[
   ["prefix-firstname", "firstname"],
   ["prefix-lastname", "lastname"]
]
```

Or

```
   ["prefix-firstname", "firstname", "prefix-lastname", "lastname"]
```

Comment: Use `.match()` or you'll have to use a loop.

Comment: It doesn't even work though.  How do I get the part that is just in the brackets of the regexp?  Match returns "prefix-firstname", "prefix-lastname"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a loop:

```
re = /prefix-(\w+)/g;
str = 'prefix-firstname prefix-lastname';
match = re.exec(str);
while (match != null) {
    match = re.exec(str);
}
```

You get each match one at a time.

---

Using match:

Here, the regex will have to be a bit different, because you cannot get sub-captures (or I don't know how to do it with multiple matches)...

```
re = /[^\s-]+(?=\s|$)/g;
str = 'prefix-firstname prefix-lastname';
match = str.match(re);
alert(match);
```

`[^\s-]+` matches all characters except spaces and dashes/hyphens only if they are followed by a space or are at the end of the string, which is a confition imposed by `(?=\s|$)`.

Answer (score 4):

This will do what you want:

```
var str="prefix-firstname prefix-lastname";
var out =[];

str.replace(/prefix-(\w+)/g,function(match, Group) {

    var row = [match, Group] 
    out.push(row);

});
```

Probably a mis-use of .replace, but I don't think you can pass a function to .match...

_Pez

Answer (score 0):

You can find the groups in two steps:

```
"prefix-firstname prefix-lastname".match(/prefix-\w+/g)
.map(function(s) { return s.match(/prefix-(\w+)/) })
```